# ORA-04063: view "MFA44.IMS_REQUEST_LIST" has errors

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm sure this issue could be resolved with just a nudge in the right direction... I altered a table called `FMS_BYLAWS` by dropping one of the columns (`PURPOSE_ID`) that referenced a table called `FMS_PURPOSES`. I instead created a new column called `PURPOSE_IDS(VARCHAR2(1000))`. This will be a collection of ids that will be handled in the application. I have a view named `IMS_REQUEST_LIST` that now has errors because I dropped this column and replaced it.

I need to know how to alter the view to get it up and running again. That or I need a way to see the original statement that created the view so I can take that and alter it. If any other information is needed just request it of me and I will deliver as best as I can! Below is the select statement for getting the text... which I don't entirely understand:

```
SQL> SELECT text FROM ALL_VIEWS WHERE VIEW_NAME = 'IMS_REQUEST_LIST';

TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
SELECT r.id            AS request_id,
r.issue_id             AS issue_id,
```

Comment: Storing a 'collection' of IDs in a string column sounds like a bad idea. It breaks normalisation and is hard to maintain. If your application wants a list of IDs then generate it on request with `listagg`, or even better return an actual collection so the application gets, say, an array - so it doesn't have to reconstruct the individual elements. Exactly how depends on your application and language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see why it is erroring in the `user_errors` view, or with `alter view ims_request_list compile` followed by `show_errors`. Presumably it refers to the dropped column; otherwise it would have been invalidated bythat drop but recompiled on next reference. That automatic recompilation is failing because it now has a syntax error.

The `all_views.text` column [is a LONG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_2133.htm). By default SQL*Plus only shows the first 80 characters of LONG, CLOB and XMLType columns. You can do [`set long 32767`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#SQPUG088) (or any large number) to see the full text.

You can also use [the `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/metadata_api.htm#SUTIL1625) to get the full `create view` statement. You will need to `set long` to see all of that too as it returns CLOB.

Answer (score 0):

Your query result is truncated. Text is a LONG column. In sqlplus issue

Set long 4000;

before running your query to get 4000 chars of text.